# Chain SSH script

Tags: linux, ssh

Let's say I have 3 linux servers.

I need a script that will login from s1 to s2 via ssh, then from s2 to s3 via ssh, then check, if there is already exists string in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys from s1 then do nothing otherwise do

```
echo '${id_rsa.pub from s1}' >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys_on_s3
```

s1 and s2 are constant, s3 can be variable.
ssh from s1 to s2 already settled up passwordless,
ssh from s2 to all s3 already settled up passwordless.

I need to have a possibility to add ip of s3 as input for script.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ProxyJump` in combination with `ssh-copy-id`

To connect s3 from s1 over s2

```
user@s1:~$ ssh -o JumpProxy=s2 s3
```

To copy your public key to s3 when it doesn't exist

```
user@s1:~$ ssh-copy-id -o JumpProxy=s2 s3
```